# session times out again after user is logged out in asp

Tags: asp.net

The program I am using is coded in C# and [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net), our session starts when the page first loads, after the time-out and the user is logged out and redirected to the log in screen the session time starts over, and times out again. this makes the user have to log in twice.

How do I change the session time so that it starts after the user logs in and the time-out does not start again until the user is logged in?

Comment: can you share some actual code with your problem , it can be a problem of web.config or global.asax file or maybe both @appel

Answer (score 0):

You can increase session time in web.config. By default it is 20 minutes, but you have to manually put the tag of session.

Answer (score 0):

inside web.config, you can set the session timeout option

web.config

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120" />
  </system.web>
```

You can increase the timeout field, this is in minute

ref: [HttpSessionState.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx)

Comment: the session timeout is not the problem, it is when the session does time out and user is sent to log in screen, that it seems like the timeout starts again here. if a user tries to log back in after timeout, they are prompt to sign in a second time